# Selenium Python find_element Xpath cant find xpath

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, xpath, findelement

I want to access an website with selenium and than a addblock-window appears, in which i need to click a button for it to disappear. [image: adblock window]

Eventhough I can find my XPath(`//button[@title='Einverstanden']`, `/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/button[@title = 'Einverstanden']` or
`//button[contains(text(),"Einverstanden")]'`) in the browser,
[image: Xpath in Browser]

I can't find it with my Python script. And i can't seem to find the mistake.

Here is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver  = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.get("``https://www.derstandard.at/story/2000134260361/endspiel-vor-gericht-prozess-gegen-boris-becker-startet-in-london``")
driver.maximize_window()
x = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@title = 'Einverstanden']")
print(x)
```

This is the error I'm getting.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button is enclosed in an `iframe` in which case, you first need to switch to the iframe and then access the element

This should work:

```
driver.get("https://www.derstandard.at/consent/tcf/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id, 'sp_message_container')]//iframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Einverstanden']"))).click()
```

Wait Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

In case you want to switch to default frame again, you may use this when required:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: May i ask why you used the function .visibility_of_element_located(By.CSS_selector and not XPAth?

Comment: You may use XPATH as well, no issues. I just picked it up the first thing that came to mind. It's a highly debatable topic that css_selector is optimzed than xpath though, but nevermind. XPATH still works and I mostly use XPATH.
XPATH for the same element would be: `//button[@title='Einverstanden']`